# Thermal conductivity and diffusivity of diatomite (also known as diatomaceous earth or kieselguhr)

Tags: thermodynamics, conductivity, thermal-conductivity

Does anyone know where can I find measured thermal conductivity and thermal diffusivity of diatomite for different temperatures? I'm looking for the temperature dependency for temperatures higher than 300K. The upper temperature limit shall be at least 1000K, but more is better. All I have found is thermal conductivity in "Touloukian, Y. S., et al. "Thermophysical properties of matter - The TPRC data series. Volume 2. Thermal conductivity - nonmetallic solids. (1971)". I'm still missing data on thermal diffusivity though, and I'd like to see more data on thermal conductivity, if available.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As a granular material the thermal diffusivity will depend greatly on things like grain size, shape, and packing density (how much you compress it). For a specific application you likely need to determine it experimentally to get a good answer.

Comment: @JonCuster, Your statement is true -- but since similar diatoms have similar shells (tests), http://www.microscopy-uk.org.uk/mag/indexmag.html?http://www.microscopy-uk.org.uk/mag/artfeb05/cbdiatoms.html, there likely would be much less variation between samples with the same origin, as opposed to ground powders, such as MgO, that have not been sieved. Results of a few tests (no pun intended) might apply to an entire source of diatomaceous earth.

Comment: Cross-posting is discouraged on the Stack Exchange network. As there are duplicates on Earth Science (https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/25763) and Matter Modeling (https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/11965), I am closing this question.